# D3 choropleth map with flexible thresholds

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, scale, threshold

I have created a choropleth map of European Union regions depicting GDP per capita.
I have set the thresholds myself, but would like to allow for user interaction.

Have found a similar type of map at the Netherlands statistics office, but this was programmed using Flash.

[Link to Netherlands map programmed using Flash](http://www.cbs.nl/en-GB/menu/themas/onderwijs/cijfers/overig/schoolverlaters.htm#)

Can anyone help me on how to do this using D3 / Javascript. If you can point me to an example that would be great.

Cheers

Daniel

Comment: You can use a quantize scale for that -- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606

Comment: Hi Lars thanks for your quick answer. I am not sure this helps though. I want to create a map where the user can interactively choose where to set the boundaries between colours using a coloured scale like in the example I linked to. I think d3.scale.threshold() is fine in this case. I just want the user to be able to adapt the thresholds using a slider. I must add: I am very enthusiastic about this stuff, but I do not have loads of experience.

Comment: Lars, I can send you the code if you want. In the code I have "manually" set the thresholds, but I would like them to be flexible and for the user to interactively adapt them via a legend scale slider.

Comment: Well the idea would be to use a threshold scale where the values in `.domain()` are set by the user like you describe. So all you'd need to add on top of the example is the slider that allows you to do that.

Comment: You'll want to check out the d3 [drag behaviour](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-drag) for simplifying the user interaction.  You'll also need a [scale invert method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_invert) to convert between screen pixels and data values.  Your array of threshold values can be used in a datajoin to create the moveable markers, and then on the drag event you update the data, update the scale, and trigger an update method that re-colours the map and redraws legends and the markers/colour blocks on the axis.